# How semaphore protect shared data?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

Why we can allow multiple threads run at the same time? (sem_init(&sem,0,5)), I think that means 5 threads can run. So why the race condition will not occur>

Comment: just read any chapter on thread synchronization on any decent C++ book/course. It will surely explain everying.

Comment: Mutual exclusion (a.k.a., "mutex") is just one of the things you can do with a _counting semaphore_. If you're going to use a counting semaphore as a mutex, then you'll probably initialize the count to 1, and the count will always either be 1 (signifying that the mutex is available,) or 0 (signifying that the mutex is locked.)

Answer (score 1):

`sem_wait` doesnt take a count it, `sem_init` that does . But your basic question is still valid.

semaphores are not generally intended to stop data races. They are used in a situation where you want a max of n consumers of something running at once.

You should use `phtread_mutex` for data race prevention

Comment: binary semaphore is very often use to stop data races. Mutex can be only released by the holding task, semaphore can be given by any task. Very convenient if you want to protect data placed in the queue to anothe process.

Comment: "Semaphore" is an old idea. It comes from a time before "atomic" instructions (TAS, CAS, LL/SC) were a common feature in computer architectures.  Semaphore was intended to be a primitive _interface_, available on many platforms, upon which, all kinds of higher-level synchronization constructs (mutexes, blocking queues, barriers, etc.) could be built.  https://greenteapress.com/wp/semaphores/